# Ошибка при компиляции кодa, при доступе к свойству объекта. TS7053. TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Не могу понять как избавиться от следующей ошибки: `error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Test'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Test'.`

Набросал упрощенный показательный пример, который выдает подобную ошибку:

```
export class Test {

email = 'some_email';

  someFunc() {
    const rule = { prop: 'email' };
    console.log(this[rule.prop]);
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
    //    "experimentalDecorators": true,           /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    //    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true             /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`"strict": false` - Убирает ошибку, но это мне кажется не решение.

Comment: сдается мне у вас ошибка не в том коде, который вы приложили. Скорее всего вы хотите перечислять св-ва класса, а у вас нет типа индекса

Comment: @ThisMan, код, который я приложил не компилируется из-за той же самой ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, достаточно добавить тип для ключа объекту, что бы `ts` знал про это

```
export class Test {
    /**
     * Говорим ts что ключ у этого класса имеет тип string.
     */
    [index: string]: any;
    email = 'some_email';

    someFunc() {
        const rule = {
            prop: 'email'
        };
        console.log(this[rule.prop]);
    }
}
```